How can I reduce the amount of resources I'm using in this system verilog design
I want to implement a design that follow a paper written by a researcher the part, this lead us to this picture that resume what the code I have so far is supposed to do:

As you can se the goal is to do a set of addition and multiplication on given indices in order to have news one that are used to do the permutation.
To do so I have the this sv code so far,
    module swap_2D_cat(
    input logic [7:0] block[31:0][31:0], // Input block of data
    input logic [19:0] kd,               // Input parameter kd
    output logic [13:0] in_out,          // Output signal in_out
    input logic clk,                     // Clock signal
    input logic rst,                     // Reset signal
    output logic [25:0] jn_out,   
    output logic [4:0]i_out,
    output logic [4:0]j_out,  
    output logic[6:0]z1_out,
    output logic[11:0]z2_out,
    output logic[11:0]z3_out,
         // Output signal jn_out
    output logic [7:0] block_out[31:0][31:0]
    
);

    // Internal signals
    logic [4:0] ud, vd, rid, rjd;
    logic [4:0] i, j;
    logic [6:0] z1;
    logic [9:0] z2_intermed_product;
    logic [11:0] z2;
    logic [9:0] z3_intermed_product;
    logic [11:0] z3;
    logic [9:0] in_intermed_1_product;
    logic [11:0] in_intermed_1_add1;
    logic [13:0] in;
    logic [23:0] jn_intermed;
    logic [25:0] jn;
    logic [7:0] temp; // Temp variable for permutation

    // Component Instantiations for the calculation of in and jn indices that we will use for swap 

    /*


        THIS PART IS INSTANTIATIOIN OF OTHER MODULES TAHT PERFORM ADDITION AND MULTIPLIACATION GOAL IS TO CREATE ACCORDING TO THE PAPER Z1 Z2 Z3 needed in the calcumation of IN JN 

    */
    fix_add #(.N(5)) add1_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, rid}),
        .addend2({{{1'b0}}, rjd}),
        .sum(z1)
    );

    fix_mult #(.INPUT_WIDTH(5), .OUTPUT_WIDTH(10)) mult1_inst (
        .multiplicand(vd),
        .multiplier(ud),
        .result(z2_intermed_product)
    );

    fix_add #(.N(10)) add2_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, z2_intermed_product}),
        .addend2(11'b00000000001),
        .sum(z2)
    );

    fix_mult #(.INPUT_WIDTH(5), .OUTPUT_WIDTH(10)) mult2_inst (
        .multiplicand(i),
        .multiplier(vd),
        .result(z3_intermed_product)
    );

    fix_add #(.N(10)) add3_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, z3_intermed_product}),
        .addend2({{6{1'b0}}, rjd}),
        .sum(z3)
    );

    fix_mult #(.INPUT_WIDTH(5), .OUTPUT_WIDTH(10)) mult3_inst (
        .multiplicand(ud),
        .multiplier(j),
        .result(in_intermed_1_product)
    );

    fix_add #(.N(10)) add4_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, in_intermed_1_product}),
        .addend2({{6{1'b0}}, i}),
        .sum(in_intermed_1_add1)
    );

    fix_add #(.N(12)) add5_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, in_intermed_1_add1}),
        .addend2({{6{1'b0}}, z1}),
        .sum(in)
    );

    fix_mult #(.INPUT_WIDTH(12), .OUTPUT_WIDTH(24)) mult4_inst (
        .multiplicand(z2),
        .multiplier({{7{1'b0}}, j}),
        .result(jn_intermed)
    );

    fix_add #(.N(24)) add6_inst (
        .addend1({{{1'b0}}, jn_intermed}),
        .addend2({{13{1'b0}}, z3}),
        .sum(jn)
    );

    /*
         Output assignments
    
    */ 
    assign jn_out = jn & 31;
    assign in_out = in & 31;
    assign ud = kd[19:15];
    assign vd = kd[14:10];
    assign rid = kd[9:5];
    assign rjd = kd[4:0];
    assign i_out=i;
    assign j_out =j;
    assign z1_out =z1;
    assign z2_out =z2;
    assign z3_out =z3;

    // Clock-driven block for iterating over the block indices
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin : proc_i_j
        if (rst) begin
            i <= 0;
            j <= 0;
        end else begin
            if (i <31) begin
                if (j <31) begin
                    j <= j + 1;
                end else begin
                   i<=i+1; 
                    j<= 0; // Reset i at the end of the iteration
                end
            end
            ///i<=0;
        end

    end
        /*

            permutation 

    */

    genvar it, jt;
    generate
        for(it = 0; it < 32; it++) begin:nom1
            for(jt = 0; jt < 32; jt++) begin: nom2
                always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin : proc_block_out
                    if (rst) begin
                        block_out[it][jt] <= it+jt;
                    end else begin
                            block_out[in_out][jn_out] <= block_out[i][j];
                            block_out[i][j] <=block_out[in_out][jn_out];
                        //end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule

In simulation, when in input I have an matrix, I get in output what I'm expecting to have, problem is when I try the synthesis, I have an error saying that my computer need more RAM to process the full synthesis of this design, but I know that it's because my design is not correct in certain way, so I'm looking for help to reduce the resources of this code or any recommendation to change the logic of this design.
this code perform the add.fix:
    module fix_add 
#(parameter N = 32)
    (
    input [N:0] addend1,
    input [N:0] addend2,
    output logic [N+1:0]sum
);
    

    always_comb begin
        if (addend1[N] == addend2[N]) begin
                sum[N+1] = addend1[N];
                sum[N:0] = addend1[N-1:0] + addend2[N-1:0]; 
             end
             // diffirent sign
             else if (addend1[N] == 0 && addend2[N] == 1) begin
                if (addend1[N-1:0] >= addend2[N-1:0]) begin
                    sum[N+1]= 0;
                    sum[N:0] = addend1[N-1:0] - addend2[N-1:0];
                end
                else begin
                    sum[N:0] = addend2[N-1:0] - addend1[N-1:0];
                    if((addend2[N-1:0] - addend1[N-1:0]) ==0)
                        sum[N+1]= 0;
                    else
                        sum[N+1] = 1;

                end
             end

             else begin
                if (addend1[N-1:0] >= addend2[N-1:0]) begin
                    sum[N:0] = addend1[N-1:0] - addend2[N-1:0];
                    if((addend1[N-1:0] - addend2[N-1:0]) ==0)
                        sum[N+1] = 0;
                    else
                        sum[N+1] = 1;
                end
                else begin
                    sum[N+1] = 0;
                    sum[N:0] = addend2[N-1:0] - addend1[N-1:0];
                end
             end
        
    end


endmodule : fix_add

module fix_add_tb;
    logic [32:0] addend1; 
    logic [32:0] addend2;
    logic [33:0] sum;


fix_add fix_add(

    .addend1(addend1),
    .addend2(addend2),
    .sum(sum)
    );


    initial begin
        
        addend1 = 32'b0;
        addend2 = 32'b0;
        
    end
    initial begin
        #2 ;
        addend1 = 33'h100001234;
        addend2 = 33'h123;
        #5;
        addend1 = 33'hffffffff;
        addend2 = 33'hffffffff;
        #10 $finish;

    end

endmodule

and this one the mult:
module fix_mult #(
  parameter INPUT_WIDTH  = 16             ,
  parameter OUTPUT_WIDTH = 2 * INPUT_WIDTH 
)
(
  input  [INPUT_WIDTH-1:0 ] multiplicand, // Multiplicand
  input  [INPUT_WIDTH-1:0 ] multiplier  , // Multiplier
  output [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1:0] result        // Result = multiplicand * multiplier
);

  //==============================================================================
  //                           Internal signals
  //==============================================================================

  logic [INPUT_WIDTH-1:0][2*INPUT_WIDTH-1:0] pre_result; // Pre result
  logic [INPUT_WIDTH-1:0][2*INPUT_WIDTH-1:0] sum       ; // Summary

  //==============================================================================
  //                               Computing
  //==============================================================================

  // pre_result
genvar i;

// Pre-calculate pre_result
generate
  for (i = INPUT_WIDTH-1; i >= 0; i--) begin : gen_pre_result
    assign pre_result[i] = ({INPUT_WIDTH{multiplier[i]}} & multiplicand[INPUT_WIDTH-1:0]) << i;
  end
endgenerate

// Calculate sum
assign sum[0] = pre_result[0];
generate
  for (i = 1; i < INPUT_WIDTH; i++) begin : gen_sum
    assign sum[i] = pre_result[i] + sum[i-1];
  end
endgenerate


  // result
  assign result = sum[INPUT_WIDTH-1];

endmodule : fix_mult

Also all the math in this code is correct so don't pay attention to much to that.

If your only running on 4G of RAM, it is very likely going to tell you your PC requires more RAM... Same with the disk space. You might consider getting an upgrade or otherwise switching to another Operating system and/or vendor tool(s).

What exactly is being implemented i.e the bigger system? Your computer needs more RAM or the FPGA?

It’s not uncommon to need 64-128GB of RAM to synthesize such code. Even some seemingly simple things I tried synthesizing from system verilog code needed 64GB.

@fabrice Could we get a source for the image?

@citizen i have 8 one my laptop but an other guy with way more heaps of ram also struggle with the synthesis part on his machine, i think that it's more a design problem

@gyuunyuu it's a design that do cryptography on images, it's my computer that need more ram says quartus prime

Why are defining your own fix_add/mult and not use +/* ? Some synthesizers have a per-defined module for multiplication, division, and complex arithmetic that can help lighten the demand for synthesizing.
